# Adding an Embedded link to displa ya webpage to aura cmp

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community

I'm trying to building a lightning component to display a report from a webpage using an embedded script.

Here is what I have so far for my cmp named TableauView.cmp:

```
<aura:component
implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" > >

    <iframe  src="<script type='text/javascript' src='https://tableau.apptoapp.org/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js'></script><div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1920px; height: 848px;'><object class='tableauViz' width='1920' height='848' style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Ftableau.apptoapp.org%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;IM' /><param name='name' value='R' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='showAppBanner' value='false' /><param name='filter' value='iframeSizedToWindow=true' /></object></div>"

            width = "100%"
            height = "500px"
            sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms"
            scrolling = "auto"/>




</aura:component>
```

I dont know if there is any JS needed for this or if its all VF but any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I should also mention, that I had a version before this that would just open up the webpage in a seperate tab/window but I need it to display in the comp itself.

Comment: Isn't that what canvas apps are for? https://www.tableau.com/sfdc-canvas-adapter